# How do I log in to "The Cloud" wifi hotspots using curl?

Tags: wireless-networking, login, curl, cloud, hotspot

In England at least, there's this accursèd thing called 'The Cloud', which increasingly provides all public wifi hotspots. Has anyone already knocked up a curl command/bash script/etc to log in to it automatically without having to start a browser and click stuff every time?